# Valid or invalid barcodes

Tags: java, arrays, barcode, barcode-scanner

1. Calculate the sum of the digits in the odd-numbered positions (the first, third, …, eleventh digits) and multiply this sum by 3.
2. Calculate the sum of the digits in the even-numbered positions (the second, fourth, …, tenth digits) and add this to the previous result.
3. If the last digit of the result from step 2 is 0, then 0 is the check digit. Otherwise, subtract the last digit from 10 to calculate the check digit.
4. If the check digit matches the final digit of the 12-digit, the barcode is assumed correct.

   for(int j = 0; j <= 10; j = j + 2)
          {

   ```
        sumOdd = sumOdd + bar[0][j];

      }

      result1 = sumOdd * 3;

      for(int j = 1; j <= 11; j = j + 2)
      {
        sumEven = sumEven + bar[0][j];


      }
      result2 = result1 + sumEven;

      if(result2 % 10 == 0)
      {
        checkDigit = 0;
      }
      else
      {
       checkDigit = 10 - result2 % 10;
      }

      if(checkDigit == bar[0][11])
      {
       System.out.printf("validated\n");
       //System.out.printf("Step1 Result: %d\n", result1);
       //System.out.printf("Step2 Result: %d\n", result2);
      }
      else 
      {
       System.out.printf("error in barcode\n");
       //System.out.printf("Step1 Result: %d\n", result1);
       //System.out.printf("Step2 result: %d\n", result2);
      }
   ```

   }

Comment: do you have any background, or did you just get some homework and didn't feel like even researching it ?

Comment: @Noctis I research alot. I just had some problems with this that's why I came here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be more like this because you have to input `n` times from the user:

```
int n = myScan.nextInt();
int[] bar = new int[n]; 
for (int i=0; i<bar.length; i++) {
        int n = myScan.nextInt(); 
        bar[i] = n; 
}
```

I consider using `long` instead of `int` in this situation.

Incase you want to store each digit in an array, you must use a multidimensional array which pretty much should be as below:

```
int number = myScan.nextInt();
int[][] bar = new int[number][12];

for (int i=0; i<bar.length; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<bar[i].length; j++) {
            int n = myScan.nextInt(); 
            bar[i][j] = n; 
    }
```

And you will have a 2D array `[x][]` where `x` will be the index number from `0-(number-1)` of the particular barcode and `[x][0]-[x][11]` will be the barcode digits at the index number `x`.

Comment: But the input depends on the user. I'll the user first then the number of barcodes that she/he will enter depends how many she entered. Like my Step 1 example

Comment: @BeginnersProblem Edited my answer. It can also store each digit of the barcode in an array. Taking input the number of Barcodes from a user is not a problem.

Comment: it has an error :(( it says "int [] [] cannot be converted to int[]" on this line of the code int[] bar = new int[number][12];

Comment: @BeginnersProblem It's just a syntax problem. I edited it. use `int[][] bar = new int[number][12]`

Comment: 1. Calculate the sum of the digits in the odd-numbered positions (the first, third, …, eleventh digits) and multiply this sum by 3.                                  2. Calculate the sum of the digits in the even-numbered positions (the second, fourth, …, tenth digits) and add this to the previous result.                         3. If the last digit of the result from step 2 is 0, then 0 is the check digit. Otherwise, subtract the last digit from 10 to calculate the check digit.                   4. If the check digit matches the final digit of the 12-digit, the barcode is assumed correct.

Comment: Those are my tasks @Mr.Robot. I do have a C version of the code but it appears only 1 barcode will only work on my code. 2D array confuses me how to calculate each barcodes.

Comment: You have to post your work/code done until now in a new question and ask the same thing and post where the problem occurs.

Comment: I've edited my post @Mr.Robot, so far that's my work. 2D array confuses me on how to calculate each of the barcodes separately.

Comment: Your method seems appropriate. But you don't need a nested for loop for `sumOdd` and `sumEven`. Just use a single for loop for a single barcode. Code your algorithm for a single barcode and then modify it for multiple barcode. However, also In your second `for loop` for `sumEven` edit it with this: (dont forget to remove one for loop from both of the nested for loop and check this algorithm for a single barcode) Do it just for `bar[0][j]` for the moment.
        `for(int j = 1; j <= 11; j = j+2)
         {
          sumEven = sumEven + bar[0][j];
         }`

Comment: I've edited my post @Mr.Robot. The one with if(checkDigit == bar[11]) says error.

Comment: @BeginnersProblem use bar[0][11] instead of bar[11]. And you still haven't edited your second `for loop` as I suggested above like this:  `for(int j = 1; j <= 11; j = j + 2)`

Comment: I've edited my code above. Hehe. Sorry, didn't notice the for(int j = 1; j <= 11; j = j + 2) only the bar[0][j].

Comment: No more errors now, but another problem. Hehe. Only one result comes out. like I've entered 2 barcodes and only 1 result displayed (valid) for 1 barcode

Comment: @BeginnersProblem No problem. If you have more algorith-based problems, I wouldn't be online on StackOverflow all the time, so if you feel the need of more help, I can give you my email because I don't think StackOverflow would let us chat on comments for an infinite time.